# Azure Function Apps - maintain max batch size with maxDequeueCount

Tags: azure-function-app

I have following host file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 3,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect with setup there could never be more than batchSize+newBatchThreshold number of instances running. But I realized when messages are dequed they are run instantly and not just added to the back of the queue. This means you can end up with a very high amount of instances causing a lot of 429 (to many requests). Is there anyway to configure the function app to just add the dequeded messages to the back of the queue?

Answer (score 0):

It was not related to dequeueCount. The problem was because it was a consumption plan, and then you cant control the amount of instances. After chaning to a Standard plan it worked as expected.